# Do i need to specify oneway binding for contentBinding in CollectionView

Tags: ember.js

Do I need to specify `oneWay` binding for `contentBinding` in `ArrayController`?

For example:

```
App.PeopleCollectionView = Ember.CollectionView.create({
  contentBinding: Ember.Binding.oneWay('App.peopleController.content')
});
```

Comment: Can you be more specific with the question? What are you trying to accomplish and why do you think oneWay binding might be the way to do it?

Comment: @LukeMelia, i am just going through the documentation of ember and was just curious if the same one way binding(for fastness) is applied to CollectionView as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can specify a one-way binding in this case for a small performance increase, provided you will not be manipulating the `content` property of your people collection view.